# what is the difference between SIMD gather and insert?

Tags: performance, memory, architecture, vectorization, simd

AFAK, both `gather` and `insert` instructions are designed for loading inconsecutive data elements from memory to vector register, but I found many papers introducing `gather` technique as a more efficient way to pack inconsecutive elements.

`insert` is easy to understand: multiple scalar load uops are issued and the coresponding data elements are loaded into vector register one by one;

`gather` needs a `base_addr` and a vector of `index`, which is added to the `base_addr` to indicate the elements to load.

But how is `gather` implemented, does it issue multiple load uops as `insert`? and what causes the performance difference compared with `insert`?

Comment: `insert` needs (at least) one *instruction* per loaded element. `gather` is a *single* instruction. Both may end up creating about the same number of *micro-operations* for loading, but if you're limited by instruction fetch, decode, branch-prediction or I-cache, `gather` is probably more efficient if the micro-architecture is optimized for it.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for the useful information. I read many papers but did not find this. May I have the reference?

Comment: There is no reference. It's basic understanding of assembly language. Which part of what I wrote requires further elaboration?

Comment: Last time I tested on a Haswell CPU, gather was actually slower than just using _mm_setr_ps, which itself used insert instructions. It may take a while for CPU's to support the instructions natively with minimal micro ops, but I would expect this to happen eventually.

Comment: Gather I see very slow. In the CPU is implemented internally no emulation, at least on Haswell. There is a section about that in the Intel optimization manual.